# Test Method order: lower level tests first?

Tags: unit-testing

Case in point:

1) One particular Test Method tests a low-level feature. Let's say it tests an instance factory.
2) A LOT of functions depend on this one low-level thing.

Now, the low-level thing is broken, and its Test Method fails.

Do I want to see it buried under hundreds of other failed tests of functionality that relies on it? Or do I want to see that one primary failure?

Just an instance of where I think you'd want to have *some* ordering of test method execution, namely: lower levels before higher ones.

Note that I do *NOT* imply a dependency for the order of Test Methods execution. No test method needs a result or state from any other test.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd rather have all the error messages to warn me of the scope of the problem - if you run your unit-tests frequently, you'll know what you changed to break them.

Comment: Agreed, anyway. Even I chose not to do it as I suggested in my question, but more in the way that it's better not going against the conventional flow. It's worthy of discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I would mock the "instance factory" in the higher level test. If one feature is breaking, preferably only the tests that test that feature should fail. You might break that feature without knowing why and then you want to see the exact feature test fail. Otherwise you might have a hard time figuring out what was broken. You can of course undo the last change to fix it, but you might still not know why everything breaks.